# Firebase Android SearchView by values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, searchview

I have worked for search about how to search in firebase by vaule and I couldn't have a fully answer so I am asking now ...

I have used this method and I couldn't get the correct result:

I need to search by "Username".

Here's my database:

[image]

```
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                    mQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild("Username");


                    return false;
                }
            });
```

And also I have used:

```
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                    mQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild("Username").equalTo(newText)


                    return false;
                }
            });
```

but I couldn't so can anyone give me fully correct answer please

---

Thanks AtaerCaner for helping me and also thanks  for trying to help me as much as you can, but I still haven't got any result from the Search View so I will give the method that is in my class:

```
mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                            String A = (String) dataSnapshot.child(Post_Key).child("Username").getValue();
                            mQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild(A).equalTo(query);


                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                            String A = (String) dataSnapshot.child(Post_Key).child("Username").getValue();
                            mQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild(A).equalTo(newText);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
```

So Please check the method if its correct or not ..

Comment: can you plz help me, how to apply search filter while using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think i'm searching Mike. First, bring all users by username with `mDatabase.child("Users").orderByChild("Username")`. But i want the Mike's datas, so i add `.equalTo("Mike")`. This returns a query as i say then set an `.addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to get datas of Mike. The information i want will come as iterable object with one item in this callback. Then cast it to your User modal.

```
mDatabase.child("Users").orderByChild("Username").equalTo("Mike").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  User user = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next().getValue(User.class);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

As far as i see in your code you get the query with `mQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild(A).equalTo(newText)` but you don't do anything with it.

Maybe this guy can help you 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WTQZV5-roY

Comment: I didn't understand well, can you explain more please because I didn't know what to do in onChildAdded method ..

Comment: You want the datas of specific user, right? In `onChildAdded ` metod, the information of the user you are looking for will return to you as dataSnapshot. Cast it to your modal and do what you want @7uthaifah

Comment: I have edited my question so check what I have done to chick if the method is correct or not

Comment: thanks AtaerCaner I have finally solve it ... thank you very much